# Best Practice in setting up a project-based app using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am working on a project-based application using Ionic2 and Firebase. My question is what is the best practice when storing data in a project-based format? I understand it should be as flat as possible.  That said, below is my current setup.

```
Firebase Data
    -Users (all auth'd users)
    -Projects (Rules allow only users authorized to access one particular project) 
        -Elements (elements within the project that are edited)
        -Forms (form items specific to a project)
        -Images (just urls & metadata, the actual image is stored in GCS)
```

Is this Best Practice? Or should I store every project's "Forms" & "Elements" objects in one node, using query and the project's ID to retrieve them?

The flow of the app is as follows:

1. The user first signs in using Firebase Auth (this data is stored in the 'user' node).
2. The user is greeted with a list of their projects (the list along with id's of the projects are stored in their user node as well).
3. When the user selects a project, I'm currently querying the entire project's node.

I'm just not sure it is most efficient to return the entire node (as it could contain hundreds or thousands of elements, images, and forms).

I am using Angularfire2 and a `FirebaseObjectObservable` to return the the entire project node in a provider (see below).

Comment: It depends on your problem and how you make queries. You can retrieve the same data with different queries, e.g. retrieving all elements of the same user, elements related to one form, etc. So to help, you need to provide more information on how you are making queries.

Comment: Thanks @TurkhanBadalov, I edited the question accordingly. Let me know if you need more context.

Comment: Actually, you guess it right that you should not load the whole content. If the data can be shown partially, then you have to implement pagination. Otherwise you have no way other than loading the whole content. But you can implement then pseudo-pagination, e.g. loading data when scrolling down. But due to the lack of context (what is the type of project, is there analogous projects on the Internet?), I can't say anything how to organize the data. But it seems okay. It is also interesting to know how you keep images. Inner structure could be useful. Mostly a simple JSON prototype for each node